# What is the age of the oldest known Bitcoin core developer?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

I am trying to compile some demographic data on who has contributed to Bitcoin so far and track how the demographics are changing over time.

Since GitHut does not show me demographic data I have attempted to use Google with limited success.

What is the age of the oldest known Bitcoin person to submit a pull request to Bitcoin core? I asked the same question about the youngest person the other day and the answers were helpful to me.

Eventually I want to try to compare the mean and median ages (and sex) of users and developers and track the changing demographic trends of each group.

Comment: This is somehow impossible to do empirical correct. A real person could have multiple github accounts and could create a virtual identity which age is not tied to a real world persons age.

Answer (score -2):

I am unsure of how old these core developers, but 2 that come to mind are Gavin Andresen and Mike Hearn. Hearn left recently  due to personal conflicts. (story [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/17/business/dealbook/the-bitcoin-believer-who-gave-up.html?_r=0))

Comment: The article says that Hearn is 31.  According to https://www.technologyreview.com/s/527051/the-man-who-really-built-bitcoin/, Andresen was 48 in 2014, so 50 or 51 this year.

Comment: Thank you for finding Andresens's age.  I agree that such a question may never be able to be answered.